# How can I make imenu work with complex LaTeX documents?

Tags: latex, auctex, imenu

I discovered a short time ago that [`M-x imenu` plays nice with LaTeX documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252032/17423) – *mostly*.  With a master/slave document setup (one file inputs another), `imenu` will not pick up on the structural elements in the child documents.

Similarly, running `M-x imenu` on the child document will not pick up on the rest of the document.

Both of these are *understandable*, but how can `imenu` be extended to 'do the right thing' here?  (Probably making use of `TeX-master-file`.)

---

I am using AucTeX, but RefTeX is a bit too heavy-weight for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd party packages imenu-anywhere and helm-imenu provide an imenu over all buffers of the same mode, which will bring you pretty close to a whole-document imenu, provided that you have all parts of the document open in buffers.

For a proper whole document menu, though specifically one that preserves the hierarchy, 
there's no way other than RefTex. Personally, I think that AUCTeX is no fun without RefTex, and would strongly recommend you to look at it again.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love RefTeX! Would never have gotten through my thesis without it. It's just a bit too heavy for a simple document :) If there's something like `reftex-toc` that provides something similar to `imenu`'s completion-based interface, that's about what I would like.